# Store console output to file in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, logging

I would like to store the console output from my javascript in a file.

Well, I would prefer to see the output in a file too see with /usr/bin/tail or other linux comand.

Does anybody know if its possible?, and How to do that?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `--enable-logging` flag to save console logs in a file `chrome_debug.log` under
`~/.config/google-chrome/chrome_debug.log`.

*Link removed because it now redirects to a very suspicious site. This is one reason we don't link offsite.*

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to use [File API](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/pub/FileSystem/) to write files to the disk. You can't just redirect the console log to file.

Answer (score 0):

check out [Sawbuck](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging), I haven't tried it yet the description is that is a GUI for logging chrome.